# C++ and wxWidgets DLL creation and use with microsoft access

Tags: c++, ms-access, dll

I have an in-house built product which has configuration software written in c++ and wxWidgets. I have had a customer request for a DLL which is register-able in microsoft access and extracts the products information (serial numbers/ firmware info etc) from the product, making it available in an access database in some form (csv ideally but anything would be good).

Is this possible? I can only find information online showing C# DLL's being register-able in ms access?

I am hoping to use the existing code for product connection and data extraction, which as i mentioned is written in c++ and wxWidgets, and add some accesser functions for the desired information. I am also hoping that with the modification of some project properties i can statically include the required resources and produce a usable c++ DLL

.h file

```
#ifdef EXIUNITINFOACCESSER_EXPORTS
#define EXIUNITINFOACCESSER_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define EXIUNITINFOACCESSER_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

// This class is exported from the exiUnitInfoAccesser.dll
extern "C" class EXIUNITINFOACCESSER_API exiUnitInfoAccesser 
{

public:

    exiUnitInfoAccesser(void);
    // TODO: add your methods here.

    char* GetUnitInfo();
};

extern "C" EXIUNITINFOACCESSER_API exiUnitInfoAccesser* 
BuildExiUnitInfoAccesser(void);

extern "C" EXIUNITINFOACCESSER_API char* GetUnitInfo(void);
```

.c++ file

```
#include "exiUnitInfoAccesser.h"

// This is an example of an exported variable
EXIUNITINFOACCESSER_API exiUnitInfoAccesser* nAccesser=0;

// This is an example of an exported function.
EXIUNITINFOACCESSER_API exiUnitInfoAccesser* 
BuildExiUnitInfoAccesser(void)
{
    exiUnitInfoAccesser* nAccesser = new exiUnitInfoAccesser(); 

    return nAccesser;
}

EXIUNITINFOACCESSER_API char* GetUnitInfo(void)
{
    return "test";
}


// This is the constructor of a class that has been exported.
exiUnitInfoAccesser::exiUnitInfoAccesser()
{
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use COM dlls (which can be written in C++ and need to be registered), or functions exported using `extern "C"` that don't need to be registered, but require a bit more work to get working on the Access side.

You can find the docs for that last option [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/excel/developing-dlls). Note that it talks about Excel, but any VBA application will handle it the same.

For COM dlls, a COM dll is a COM dll, no matter if it's written in C#, C++, VB.Net or something else entirely. The same rules apply.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i have it building and registering fine now. Just have to actually implement the functions correctly and i'm there

Comment: Hi again Erik A, I have implemented some basic function that just return strings however when i register the DLL in ms access none of the members seem to be visible in the object browser and i get a 'user-defined type not defined' error when i declare the DLL object. I have used dependency walker on the DLL and it shows the functions i created being exported so not sure what i'm doing wrong, any ideas?

Comment: Did you include a type library (.tlb) when compiling and registering? VBA requires that. Also, depending on the class type, the methods might not show up in the object browser. If you use the AutoDual class interface, they should show up, but that has some disadvantages

Comment: Hi Erik A, thanks for the help. I have included the .tlb on registration but not compilation. when i register with regasm.exe i use the /tlb parameter and the .tlb file is generated automatically. Is this correct? aslo how would i go about the inclusion of said .tlb file during compilation (i'm using vs2010 express)? I have tried un-registering and re-registering the dll as i read online that when changing the dll it should be re-registered and not just copy and pasted in the system dir. After re-registering i still do not have access to the dll's functions. I am wondering if it is my coding..

Comment: @bobula85 Hmm... I'm not familiar with VS 2010, but if you manually create it using regasm that should be fine too. Might be a problem on the VBA side of things. Try using late binding to use your object in VBA (you're not using events, right?), so `Dim myObject As Object`, and then `Set myObject = CreateObject("MyComLib.SomeObjectType")`. That usually throws more descriptive error messages too.

Comment: Hi, I have used the late binding version (no events within the Dll but a button click in Access) but still the same 'user defined' error. I have updated the post with the very basic code i have written, Can you spot any glaring errors?

Comment: I'll try to have a look in the next few days, my C++ is rusty as hell, I mainly do C# for COM classes, but see a few oddities.

Comment: Ok thanks, that would be great if you could. I have the more descriptive error message from the use of late binding (implemented it incorrectly before). i get 'error '429' activex component can't create object' which points to a registration issue maybe?

Comment: Yup, that's the error message I expected. It's either a registration or instantiation issue. One of the most common issues is a mismatch in bitness (it's registered as a 64-bit COM object which is default, while you're running 32-bit Office/VBA). But if I have the time, I'll check if I can reproduce the issue. I only have VS 2018, though, but don't think that'll be an issue.